# Django: Return back from POST-redirect in Chrome without dublicate pages

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, redirect, post-redirect-get

I have a detail-page, with a button that submits a GET or a POST request (tried both). This request performs an action and redirects to the same detail-page (thus refreshing it). Everything seems to be fine in Firefox, but in Chrome when I press Back Button, I get back on the same page again (so redirecting to the same page creates dublicates of this page in browser history). Can I somehow change this behaviour and remove those dublicates in Chrome also?